# Grabbing the end of a URL string and inserting it into a form field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, parsing

I have an embedded form on my website. I'm trying to grab the end of the URL after the last forward slash and then make that populate in a form field. There will be several instances of the end of the URL and I need it to print on the backend so I can match it with other information entered in the form. I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
$url = "http://umoem.stage3.commercialprogression.net/hail/jsharer0001";
$lastSegment = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

$(document).click(function() {$("#form_230f1916-6f5f-460d-a6d9-5d2233010684").print $lastSegment;});
```

form_230f1916-6f5f-460d-a6d9-5d2233010684 is the id of the form field I'm trying to fill. I'm new to script, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming `print` is a javascript function, `<?php echo $lastSegment; ?>` instead of `$lastSegment` should do what you are intending.

Comment: You're mixing PHP and Javascript.  They aren't the same thing and can't be used interchangeably.  Also, to assign a value to a (text) field with jQuery, use the `.val()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlSplit = url.split("/");
var lastString = urlSplit[urlSplit.length - 1];
```

Comment: Could you add more details, such as its output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the jquery .val() function as well.  Here is another way to do it.

```html
<?php
//set the URL you want to parse
$url = "http://umoem.stage3.commercialprogression.net/hail/jsharer0001";
//convert it into an array
$segments = explode("/",$url);
//get the last segment of the array
$lastSegment = end($segments);

 ?>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="form_230f1916-6f5f-460d-a6d9-5d2233010684" id="form_230f1916-6f5f-460d-a6d9-5d2233010684" />
  </form>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      //set the value of this field to $lastSegment
      $("#form_230f1916-6f5f-460d-a6d9-5d2233010684").val( '<?php echo $lastSegment; ?>' );
      //console.log($("#form_230f1916-6f5f-460d-a6d9-5d2233010684"));
    })
  </script>
```